# Extract only specific data from log lines

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I would like to know how can I grab in Linux only a specific pattern from each line.

Eg.

```
[...] size=4343, [...]
[...] size=4431, [...]
[...] size=3343, [...]
```

I would like to extract only size=XXXX from each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `egrep` with `-o` option

```
egrep  -o "size=[0-9]*"
```

- `-o` Prints only the matching part of the lines.
- `[0-9]*` matches zero or more digits.

**Test**

```
$ egrep  -o "size=[0-9]*" test
size=4343
size=4431
size=3343
```

Comment: Why are you using egrep, normal grep works exactly the same in this situation ?

Comment: grep: invalid option -- o
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.

Comment: which platform you are using the grep on?